# Swiping Navigation

Tags: android-listview, android-viewpager, android-scrollview, android-gesture

I have a list view of all my Facebook friend lists. I want clicking on an item from the list view to display a detailed view of the friend. Now I want to slide this detail view of the items to show the detail view of next item in the list. Similarly previous item for left to right.

I have tried using information from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12970249/android-swipe-left-or-right-to-slide-views), but I want to use view pager and page adapter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should look at the sample that comes with the sdk which uses a pager adapter and a dummy fragment for data...