# Slide menu with Expandable listView

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Probably you do not get my question. i made the expandable sliding menu on the main page..now when i open an activity from the expandable sliding menu it works will..but from that opened activity i cant slide my expandable list view which i have on the main page. i want it to be just like a facebook or a gmail but with expandable list..i have chapters and in each chapter i have different topics so if i open on chapter from the expandable list, then i cant direct slide my expandable list from that chapter and for that i have to go back to slide it again.
here is my code....``

my new adapter

```
 package com.example.drawerlayouttest;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseExpandableListAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public class NewAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    public ArrayList<String> groupItem, tempChild;
    public ArrayList<Object> Childtem = new ArrayList<Object>();
    public LayoutInflater minflater;
    public Activity activity;
    private final Context context;

    public NewAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<String> grList, ArrayList<Object> childItem) {
        this.context = context;
        groupItem = grList;
        this.Childtem = childItem;
    }

    public void setInflater(LayoutInflater mInflater, Activity act) {
        this.minflater = mInflater;
        activity = act;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
            boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        tempChild = (ArrayList<String>) Childtem.get(groupPosition);
        TextView text = null;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = new TextView(context);
        }
        text = (TextView) convertView;
        text.setText(tempChild.get(childPosition));
        text.setPadding(140, 20, 20, 20);
        text.setTextSize(16);

//      convertView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
//          @Override
//          public void onClick(View v) {
//              Toast.makeText(activity, tempChild.get(childPosition),
//                      Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//          }
//      });
        convertView.setTag(tempChild.get(childPosition));
        return convertView;
    }



    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        return ((ArrayList<String>) Childtem.get(groupPosition)).size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return groupItem.size();
    }

    @Override
    public void onGroupCollapsed(int groupPosition) {
        super.onGroupCollapsed(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public void onGroupExpanded(int groupPosition) {
        super.onGroupExpanded(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
            View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        tempChild = (ArrayList<String>) Childtem.get(groupPosition);
        TextView text = null;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = new TextView(context);
        }
        text = (TextView) convertView;
        text.setText(tempChild.get(groupPosition));
        text.setPadding(100, 20, 20, 40);
        text.setTextSize(20);


//      convertView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
//          @Override
//          public void onClick(View v) {
//              Toast.makeText(activity, tempChild.get(childPosition),
//                      Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//          }
//      });
        convertView.setTag(tempChild.get(groupPosition));
        return convertView;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return false;
    }

}
```

(Main Activity)

```
 package com.example.drawerlayouttest;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener;


public class DrawerLayoutTest extends Activity implements OnChildClickListener {

    private DrawerLayout drawer;
    private ExpandableListView drawerList;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_drawer_layout_test);

        setGroupData();
        setChildGroupData();

        initDrawer();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.drawer_layout_test, menu);
        return true;
    }

    private void initDrawer() {
        drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

        drawerList = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

        drawerList.setAdapter(new NewAdapter(this, groupItem, childItem));

        drawerList.setOnChildClickListener(this);


    }

    public void setGroupData() {
        groupItem.add("TechNology");
        groupItem.add("Mobile");
        groupItem.add("Manufacturer");
        groupItem.add("Extras");
    }

    ArrayList<String> groupItem = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<Object> childItem = new ArrayList<Object>();

    public void setChildGroupData() {
        /**
         * Add Data For TecthNology
         */
        ArrayList<String> child = new ArrayList<String>();
        child.add("Java");
        child.add("Drupal");
        child.add(".Net Framework");
        child.add("PHP");
        childItem.add(child);

        /**
         * Add Data For Mobile
         */
        child = new ArrayList<String>();
        child.add("Android");
        child.add("Window Mobile");
        child.add("iPHone");
        child.add("Blackberry");
        childItem.add(child);
        /**
         * Add Data For Manufacture
         */
        child = new ArrayList<String>();
        child.add("HTC");
        child.add("Apple");
        child.add("Samsung");
        child.add("Nokia");
        childItem.add(child);
        /**
         * Add Data For Extras
         */
        child = new ArrayList<String>();
        child.add("Contact Us");
        child.add("About Us");
        child.add("Location");
        child.add("Root Cause");
        childItem.add(child);
    }

    @Override

    public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
            int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {

            switch (groupPosition){

         case 0:
             switch (childPosition){
             case 0:
                 Intent Intent = new Intent(this,Java.class);
                 startActivity(Intent);
                 break;
                     case 1:
                         Intent Intent1=new Intent(this,Apple.class);
                         startActivity(Intent1);
                         break;
                     case 2:
                         Intent Intent2=new Intent(this,Java.class);
                         startActivity(Intent2);
                         break;
                     case 3:
                         Intent Intent3=new Intent(this,Apple.class);
                         startActivity(Intent3);
                         break;

                 }
         case 1:
             switch (childPosition){

                     case 1:
                         Intent Intent1=new Intent(this,Apple.class);
                         startActivity(Intent1);
                         break;
                     case 2:
                         Intent Intent2=new Intent(this,Java.class);
                         startActivity(Intent2);
                         break;
                     case 3:
                         Intent Intent3=new Intent(this,Apple.class);
                         startActivity(Intent3);
                         break;

             }

        return false;
        }
            return false;

    }   
}
```

(MY XML FILE)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <!-- The navigation drawer -->

    <ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="#6B8E23" 
        android:divider="#272727"
        android:dividerHeight="0.5dp" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want Expandable list in main page and slid menu first get this [project](https://github.com/akotoe/android-slide-out-menu) then put your Expandable list instead of list in project, if you have problem with that tel me

Comment: what you mean i lost sliding menu?

Comment: i mean that when java activity opens then i can,t slide the menu. for the sliding menu i have to go back ... i want that if my java activity opens then i also can slide my expandable listview from the java activiy?

Comment: where you define sliding menu?

Comment: so how you implement sliding menu? because I don't see in your code.what you want exactly? menu like `facebook` that contain expandable list?

Comment: yes absolutely...i have given my code which is at the top...the code is given by me..please look the code

Comment: and you want put your expandable list in menu? or in main page?

Comment: i want to put my expandable list in main page.

Comment: you can use one button to do that or use gesturedetector

Comment: can you please edit my this source code and give it to me..i dont know how to do it

Comment: looks same no change? where is the change?

Comment: what you want change?I just separate your class and xml from each other. you want the right Code? ops, excuse me but I dont have a time.

Comment: see this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12970249/android-swipe-left-or-right-to-slide-views

Comment: @user2592807 i follow your above code for building navigation drawer using expandable listview, but i got this error `java.util.arraylist cannot be cast to java.lang.charsequence` on `getChildView` and `getGroupView` when i try to cast `text.setText(tempChild.get(childPosition));` and also `text.setText(tempChild.get(groupPosition));` to this `text.setText((CharSequence) tempChild.get(childPosition));` & `text.setText((CharSequence) tempChild.get(groupPosition));` can anybody help me?